# Representing $n!$ as a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factorial, binomial-theorem

For $n\in\mathbb N$, $n!$ could, theoretically, be expanded into a polynomial of degree $n$ as $$\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots  \left(n-(n-2)\right) (n-(n-1))}_{n \ \text{factors}} =\sum_{k=0}^n a_k n^k $$ How can I determine the coefficients $a_k$?

For the $n^n$ term, there is only one choice, as every factor must contribute an $n$. So $a_n$ should be $1$.

For the $n^{n-1}$ term, we need $n-1$ factors to contribute an $n$, and the remaining factor multiples it with a constant term. So, $$a_{n-1} = -\sum_{i=0}^n i$$and so on. But I’m not sure if what I’m doing really makes sense. Does such a polynomial represention of $n!$ really exist?

Comment: $n!$ is not a polynomial and you cannot find $a_k$'s unless you make them dependent on $n$. If you make them dependent on $n$ then they are not unique. There are plenty of choices.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How are they not unique?

Comment: You could argue $n!$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ is some "limit" of those polynomials by calling the $k$th such polynomial $P(k)$ and noting $k! = P(k)$ for all $1 \le k \le n$, but I have no idea if there is any way to make that formal or useful

Comment: Note these polynomials are usually written as $(x)_n$, using the notation of the [Falling Factorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html)

Comment: $a_k=\frac {n!} {n^{n}}$ for $k=n$ and $0$ for $k <n$ is one choice. $a_k=n!$ for $k=0$ and $0$ for $k >1$ is another choice.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I feel you are misinterpreting the question. The OP does not appear to be asking how to write $n!$ as a polynomial with coefficients being functions of $n$, but is instead asking for the coefficients in $(x)_n$, which is a well-defined and non-trivial problem... the OP just appears to have worded this somewhat poorly

Comment: The number of factors on the left side is not fixed. It depends on $n$. That is why your idea is wrong and $n!$ is not  a polynomial in $n$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That reference is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: By noting that $(x)_{n+1} = (x-n)(x)_n = x (x)_n - n (x)_n$, so by expanding and comparing equal powers on both sides, we find (letting $b_k$ be the $k$th coefficient of $(x)_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ be the $k$th coefficient of $(x)_n$) that $b_{n+1} = a_n$ (so the first coefficient will always be $1$), $b_0 = -na_0$ (so the last coefficient will be an alternating factorial), and $b_k = a_{k-1} - n a_{k}$ for the rest of the coefficients, which appears nontrivial to me. I am not sure if the resulting list of numbers has a known name, but you can use the recurrences I gave to recursively calculate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the functions $(x)_n = x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$
, which are known as the [Falling Factorials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html). Expressed as polynomials, these have the [Stirling Numbers of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) as their coefficients.

To be specific, we have $(x)_n = \sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k) x^n$ where $s(n,k)$ denotes the $(n,k)$th Stirling Number of the First Kind. From the definition of $(x)_n$ we can, with a little tinkering, find that $s(n+1,k) = s(n,k+1) - n s(n,k)$ (see my comments above) which allows the coefficients to be recursively calculated as desired.